# Why require only R >= 3.3.0?

Tags: r, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm building a R model in Azure machine learning with a zipped xgboost package attached to the 'execute R script'.

Azure machine learning uses R 3.2.2.

The model returns with an error saying "This is R 3.2.2, package 'xgboost' needs >= 3.3.0".

Is there any reason it insists on >= 3.3.0. If not, can I get it down to run with R 3.2.2?

Comment: The message is pretty clear: `xgboost` needs R 3.3.0 or higher. Either upgrade R or use an older version of `xgboost` (from https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/xgboost/).

Comment: The specific reason is that in the package DESCRIPTION file, the Depends field is : R(>=3.3.0).

Comment: Following up on Nicola's comment, in case you want to use an older Windows binary instead of a tarball: http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/